# When multiclassing, can you keep leveling up your original class?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Like if you start out as a level 1 rogue, and then at level 5 you take a level in bard. Then you level up bard to level 3, making you a level 8 character, can you then go back to rogue and keep leveling that up?

Answer (score 11):

#### Yes

In fact, in 3.5, you were *supposed to*: 3.5 penalized you if you had classes with too-different levels, so you were supposed to keep them within 1 of each other by alternating. These were extremely unpopular rules that almost no one used, and Paizo replaced them with the much-better Favored Class rules, but they did exist.

Do note that Pathfinder generally makes multiclassing a poor idea; you tend to lose far, far more than you gain by doing so. Paizo was very heavy-handed in its attack on what it perceived to be too much multiclassing in 3.5.